# English translation of "I will not see the famous Phaedra"?

Tags: russian-language, translation, osip-mandelstam

Is there is any professional English translation of "I will not see the famous Phaedra" (Я не увижу знаменитой «Федры») by Osip Mandelstam. Can anyone provide a link where it can be found.

Comment: What do you mean by "professional English translation"?

Comment: I mean by human. It is easy to get it by google translate, but I do not like the quality, even though English is not my native.

Comment: There is a translation [here](https://kb.osu.edu/bitstream/handle/1811/49878/Goldberg_Book4CD.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) that looks okay to me (let me note that human translations aren't a good guarantee of quality; some human translations of French poetry you find on the internet are absolutely terrible). However, since I don't read any Russian, I can't judge it myself.

Comment: Put it as answer I will accept it. It is better than Google translate. I feel this particular poem is difficult to translate. Do you feel "And the diction, inflamed by indignation,
Strikes a mournful temper" is the normal English or it would be hard to remember. In Russian its equivalent is hard to remember.

Comment: It's not everyday English ... I would say it's poetic language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a translation [here](https://kb.osu.edu/bitstream/handle/1811/49878/Goldberg_Book4CD.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), in the book *Mandelstam, Blok, and the boundaries of mythopoetic symbolism* by Stuart Goldberg, that looks okay to me (although I can't say for sure, since I don't read Russian). It starts:

> I will not see the celebrated *Phèdre*
> In a venerable, many-tiered theater,
> From the high, soot-smoked gallery,
> By the light of guttering candles.

Comment: Congrats on 5k reputation and the final beta-site privilege level :-)